# Update nested array value in yaml with yq

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helmfile, yq

Given a yaml file (helmfile) like the following

```
releases:
  - chart: ../charts/foo
    name: foo
    namespace: '{{ .Values.stack }}'
    values:
      - ../config/templates/foo-values.yaml.gotmpl
    set:
      - name: image.tag
        value: 22
      - name: replicas
        value: 1
  - chart: ../charts/bar
    name: bar
    namespace: '{{ .Values.stack }}'
    values:
      - ../config/templates/bar-values.yaml.gotmpl
    set:
      - name: image.bar_proxy.tag
        value: 46
      - name: image.bar.tag
        value: 29
      - name: replicas
        value: 1
```

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to update a specific image tag. For example, I'd like to update `image.bar_proxy.tag` from `46` to `51`.

I have the following, which does the job, but it requires that you know the exact index of the array item:

```
yq -y '.releases[] |= if .name=="bar" then .set[0].value |= 51 else . end' helmfile-example.yaml
```

So if the array order were to change at some point this would break.

A preferred solution would be: "update image.bar_proxy.tag value from `46` to `51` where set[].name==image.bar_proxy.tag". Any ideas on how to achieve a more specific conditional selection like this?

FYI our yq version:

```
$ yq --version
yq 2.10.0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following filter to make it work. It works by dynamically selecting the index of the object where your tag exists. On the selected object `.value=51` will update the value as you wanted. You can also use the `-i` flag to do in-place modification of the original file.

```
yq -y '.releases[].set |= map(select(.name == "image.bar_proxy.tag").value=51)' yaml
```

See the underlying `jq` filter acting on the JSON object at [jq-playground](https://jqplay.org/s/lOYEE1IyQd)

Comment: using yq=4.9.1,  unknown shorthand flag: 'y' in -y

Comment: @SHAHS: This answer is with https://github.com/kislyuk/yq, if you have the Go version mikefarah/yq, please ask a separate question

Comment: In case it helps others, I was trying to update repository in requirements.yaml file of a helm chart, managed to do it via

yq  e '.dependencies[] |= select(.name == "test-chart") .repository=<repo-url> requirements.yaml

Comment: ok thanks for clarification, I did not realize it was different yq implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context of using Helmfile, there are a couple of ways you can approach this without necessarily editing the `helmfile.yaml`.  Helmfile allows using the Go `text/template` language in many places, similarly to the underlying Helm tool, and has some other features that can help.

One of the easiest things you can do is take advantage of `values:` being a list, and of unknown values generally being ignored.  You (or your CI/CD system) can write a separate YAML file that contains just the tags (JSON may be easier to write and is valid YAML)

```yaml
# tags.yaml
image:
  tag: 22
  bar: {tag: 29}
  bar_proxy: {tag: 46}
```

and then include this file as an additional file in the `helmfile.yaml`.  (This would be equivalent to using `helm install -f` with multiple local values files, rather than `helm install --set` individual values.)

```yaml
releases:
  - name: foo
    values:
      - ../config/templates/foo-values.yaml.gotmpl
      - tags.yaml
    # no `set:`
  - name: bar
    values:
      - ../config/templates/bar-values.yaml.gotmpl
      - tags.yaml
      - replicas: 1
    # no `set:`
```

Helmfile's templating extensions also include [`env`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templating_funcs/#env) and [`requiredEnv`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templating_funcs/#requiredenv) to read ordinary environment variables from the host system.  Helm proper does not have these to try to minimize the number of implicit inputs to a chart, but for Helmfile it's a possible way to provide values at deploy time.

```yaml
releases:
  - name: bar
    set:
      - name: image.bar_proxy.tag
        value: {{ env "BAR_PROXY_TAG" | default "46" }}
      - name: image.bar.tag
        value: {{ requiredEnv "BAR_TAG" }}
```